# Why backquoting a shell command including a kill changes its behavior?

Tags: shell

I am trying to add a timeout on a shell command. Concretely speaking, on nmblookup. As it's very fast for device supporting this query on my LAN, I want to add a timeout of 1 sec on the call. So I don't loose time with other devices

Using the following call in shell script works very fine (try it with a dummy $IP):

```
(nmblookup -A $IP | grep '#00' | grep -v GROUP | awk '{print $1}') & WPID=$!; sleep 1 && kill $WPID > /dev/null 2>&1 & wait $WPID
```

However, as I want to capture the output, I backquotes this call.. And doing so, the kill doesn't seem to be executed (on the right process?) anymore...

```
Host=`(nmblookup -A $IP | grep '#00' | grep -v GROUP | awk '{print $1}') & WPID=$!; sleep 1 && kill $WPID > /dev/null 2>&1 & wait $WPID`
```

Any idea what can be changed in the call here above to work within backquotes too ?

Thx a lot in adv for any tip!!!

V.

PS: Actually, I want to use this call in a php script... So I can't escape the use to backquotes... (I think). Otherwise, this would have been an option:

```
(nmblookup -A $IP | grep '#00' | grep -v GROUP | awk '{print $1}' > "$BASEDIR/hostname") & WPID=$!; sleep 1 && kill $WPID > /dev/null 2>&1 & wait $WPID
read -r Host < "$BASEDIR/hostname"
```

PPS: I tried also this approach without further success:

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
echo "(nmblookup -A $IP | grep '#00' | grep -v GROUP | awk '{print $1}') & WPID=\$!; sleep 1 && kill \$WPID > /dev/null 2>&1 & wait \$WPID" > "$BASEDIR/execlimit"
chmod 775 "$BASEDIR/execlimit"
Host=`$BASEDIR/execlimit`
```

Notice that calling execlimit without backquotes works fine... It only fails to kill the command when called within backquotes... So, I am not convinced that the problem is with escaping the $ signs...

Answer (score 1):

The parameter expansions are all performed *before* the command substitution actually runs. Just escape the dollar signs so that they are preserved until the command executes thes commands.

```
Host=$( (nmblookup -A $IP | grep '#00' | grep -v GROUP | awk '{print $1}') &
         WPID=\$!; sleep 1 && kill \$WPID > /dev/null 2>&1 & wait \$WPID)
```

Comment: This is returning "Illegal number: $WPID". Notice: Before posting here, I also tried to put such a call in a separated script (with an hardcoded IP) and execute that script from the shell. It worked as expected if I simply called the script (Ex.: ./exec.sh). But the kill didn't work if I called the script in backquotes (Ex.: `./exec.sh`)

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem seems to be with the PID catched within WPID when I am backquoting the call (I did add a call to 'ps' next to it and it was not the expected PID...)

I have therefore rewritten my call to get for sure the PID to be killed (it works now fine from my php script):

```
`nmblookup -A $IP > ./hostname & WPID=\$!; sleep 1 && kill \$WPID > /dev/null 2>&1 & wait \$WPID`;
$host = `grep '#00' ./hostname | grep -v GROUP | awk '{print $1}'`;
`rm -f ./hostname`;
```

In php, $ signs reference variables, so, they must indeed be escaped to be passed as-is (as text) to the shell (otherwise, php would replaced them by "their value")

Comment: Why in the world would you put backticks around `rm -f`? What does that accomplish?

Comment: As I said, it's used in a php script. Backquotes in php are an alias for shell_exec().